# How can I show and hide in JSP not included afterimage

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, jsp

Well, I do maintain the Jsp file.

[image]

You can see above the picture. a, b, c is a same file and d is another file.

You should write and submit like a -> b -> c -> d.

We have two buttons. One is 'back' and the other is 'next'

When moving in 1.jsp like a-> b -> c or c -> b -> a, then each div show or hide. However, when you click the 'next' button in c to the d, then the data go to the backend and move to 2.jsp(d).

But when you click the 'back' in the d, you go to a!!

So, I should fix this problem that it go to 'c' not 'a'.

Bellow is the As-is source.

```
$("div[id ^= guideDepth_]").each(function(idx, item){

   $(item).hide();

   if((idx + 1) == depth){

     $(item).show();

   }

}
```

depth is a(1), b(2), c(3)

So, I think if I give 'depth' 3 then it might go well.

But there is one problem or a little bit pissy.

Because there is afterimage from a. So there is any method I can show c(3) smoothly? Not included afterimage from a?

When you click the 'back' button in d(4), then it go to backend and move to 1.jsp. After it, the jquery works.

Comment: How do you want to fix it?

Comment: I want to just show the part c not with a hide and b hide. Because the a, b, c is in same jsp file. So, when I do hide a and hide b before show c. Then, the a, b is displayed in the blink of an eye!!

Comment: Then you should remove `$(item).hide();` from the cycle.